# Preloading / Prefetching Anticipated Next Assets into Browser Cache -?

Tags: performance, caching, optimization, browser, prefetch

1) Let's say for each of my key landing pages, I have established a list of the next page and its assets that I know are really likely to be requested next by the user. I would like to push these assets into the browser's cache after the initial page has fully loaded while the browser is idle (after onload event?). This would reduce load time for common navigation paths with all the implied UX and conversion benefits.

2) What are the best practices for this type of tech? What's the best starting point for a small business to experiment with rolling this out in the simplest and least expensive way? So far, some good leads I have found is [How can I preload a page using HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830675/how-can-i-preload-a-page-using-html5) and a proprietary method at **Point 3** of http://www.strangeloopnetworks.com/products/overview/how-it-works/ ... I would appreciate some other pointers or eye openers from anyone that has already done some implementations. Apologies for vagueness.