# Window.location after finish loading external page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can I show a page after finish loading?

1) Open my page.
2) Begin load external page.
3) Open external page through `window.location`

I need have an event that the page is loaded and without iframe.
P.s: page full loaded (DOM and all images).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I preload a page using HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830675/how-can-i-preload-a-page-using-html5)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can do something like this.

```
// JS
$(function(){

    var external_page =  $('#external_page');

    external_page.ready(function(){

        // This will be executed when the iframe is done loading.
        alert('Page is done loading');

        window.location.href = external_page.attr('src');
    });
});

 <!-- HTML -->
<iframe src="http://api.jquery.com" id="external_page"></iframe>

 /* CSS */
 iframe#external_page {display: none;}
```